# Play iTunes song preview in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes

I am trying to play the iTunes song preview in an iPhone app I am making. Nothing I have tried has worked.

```
    NSString *urlstr=@"http://a558.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/115/Music/ce/7d/9d/mzm.jkcgzvnm.aac.p.m4a";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];
player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare a variable *player in the class interface. 
In your example variable player will be destroyed after the current method because it is declared within a method.